# Swift - Renaming UILabel on Load

Tags: ios, swift, realm, realm-mobile-platform, apple-developer

I'm currently trying to make a website that displays a random Realm database value. I got the database collection working fine, but the problem is coming from displaying that within my app.

I currently have a UILabel, and I'm trying to use the built in viewDidLoad() function to set the text of the label with a value from my database. It's giving me a null error, how do I fix this?

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift

class Results_ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var MovieTitleLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let realm = try! Realm()
        let results = realm.objects(Movies.self)
        let randomNumber = Int.random(in: 0 ..< 5)

        let titleResult = results[randomNumber].title
        let descResult = results[randomNumber].desc
        let streamServicesResult = results[randomNumber].streamServices

        MovieTitleLabel.text = titleResult

    }
}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow and Swift. In Swift we  ALWAYS let variable names start with a lowercase, so your label should be named `movieTitleLabel`. You let `randomNumber` be between 0 and 4, bur what happens if the array `results` is shorter than 5 elements (last element has index 4)?? :)

Comment: Make sure your IBOutlet is connected to UILabel in storyboard or XIB

Comment: Try to ensure that your random index is actually within bounds of `results`, e.g. by changing `Int.random(in: 0 ..< 5)` to `Int.random(in: 0 ..< results.count)`. Other common things to check: is your view controller instantiated with the correct layout (storyboard or xib file)? Is the IBOutlet connected correctly? Does `results` at runtime contain what you think it contains (you can use a break point to check)?

Comment: What line gives you a null error?